# javascript copy object into referenced memory

Tags: javascript, object, reference

For a given variable of type Object in javascript called Dest, I want to make what it *references* to change to the value of an object called Value. Assume there is a magical statement SetDestAs(Dest, Value) that does this

E.g.

```
var dest = { a : 3, b : 3};
var ptr = dest;
// ptr.a === 3;
SetDestAs(dest, {a  : 0, b : 3 });
// dest.a === 0
// ptr.a === 0;
```

How could I implement SetDestAs?

What I don't want to do specifically is for SetDestAs to change the object which dest refers to. In the example above, it's very important that the change pesists into ptr as well.

Comment: `Object.assign(dest, {a: 0, b: 3})`

Comment: Depending on your application, it might be better to use another level of indirection, e.g. `data = { dest: { a: 3, b: 3 } };` and have `ptr` operate on `data`. That way you can just reassign `data.dest = { what: "ever", i: "want" };` and still use `ptr.dest`.

Comment: Indirection is a nice idea but it's too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to tell what you want to do, so two answers:

1. You can change the *properties* of the object `dest` refers to:

```
Object.assign(dest, {a: 0, b: 3});
```

...which is what I think you want to do. Example:

```js
var dest = { a : 3, b : 3};
var ptr = dest;
console.log(ptr.a);  // 3
Object.assign(dest, {a: 0, b: 3});
console.log(dest.a); // 0
console.log(ptr.a);  // 0
```

2. If you want to change *which object* both `dest` and `ptr` refer to, with only `dest` as your starting point, you can't do that. There's nothing you can do, starting with `dest`, that will change what object `ptr` refers to.

Comment: Options 2, is not the same.  is that deliberate?

Comment: @Keith - Right. Otherwise, there'd be no need to provide two options. But I just realized the `ptr` bit makes option 2 make no sense. :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought  :)

Comment: Nice this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: option 2 would be insane obviously